# Using isSet() vs getRemovedFields() to identify inaccessible fields after stripInaccessible()

Tags: apex, security

I am wondering is there a difference between `isSet()` and `getRemovedFields()` to identify inaccessible fields that were removed by the `stripInaccessible()` method.

From the official documentation [Enforce Security With the stripInaccessible Method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_with_security_stripInaccessible.htm):

> To identify inaccessible fields that were removed, you can use the `isSet` method.

```
SObjectAccessDecision securityDecision = Security.stripInaccessible(sourceRecords);
Contact c = securityDecision.getRecords()[0];
System.debug(c.isSet('social_security_number__c')); // prints "false"
```

Also there is another example, but this time with `getRemovedFields()`:

```
   Security.SObjectAccessDecision securityDecision =
            Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.READABLE,
            [SELECT Name, BudgetedCost, ActualCost FROM Campaign];
            );

    // Construct the output table
    if (securityDecision.getRemovedFields().get('Campaign').contains('ActualCost')) {
        for (Campaign c : securityDecision.getRecords()) {
            //System.debug Output: Name, BudgetedCost
        }
    } else {
        for (Campaign c : securityDecision.getRecords()) {
            //System.debug Output: Name, BudgetedCost, ActualCost
        }
    }
```

We could easily write `securityDecision.getRecords()[0].isSet('ActualCost')` to check if ActualCost is inaccessible. So what is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sObject#isSet` is a method that simply tells you if the field is set to a value.

> Returns information about the queried sObject field. Returns true if the sObject field is populated, either by direct assignment or by inclusion in a SOQL query. Returns false if the sObject field is not set. If an invalid field is specified, an SObjectException is thrown.

It specifically notes:

> The isSet method doesn’t check if a field is accessible to a specific user via org permissions or other specialized access permissions.

So, technically, this method is used simply to check if the value is set. You can use this in other contexts outside of Security.stripInaccessible, such as to check if a SOQL query included a given field (useful for dynamic apex). You'd have to check the pre-stripped records and post-stripped records to determine if a field was removed via System.stripInaccessible (versus if it was ever set to begin with).

The correct way to check specifically for removed fields would be getRemovedFields.